# Is there something wrong return UITextField object like this in ARC mode?

Tags: iphone, memory, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks

I use ARC in xcode and write the convenience method like this:

```
    +(UITextField *) addTextField:(NSString *)text x:(int)_x y:(int)_y width:(int)_width height:(int)_height {
       UITextField *v_txt = [[UITextField alloc] init];
       v_txt.frame= CGRectMake(_x, _y, _width, _height);
       v_txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
       return v_txt;
}
```

Many View Controllers call this class method to return the auto released `UITextField` objects in my application. Is there some memory leaks here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will handle `v_txt`  as `autorelease`. So no memory leak in your code.

And just for your guidance, please try to **follow variable naming conventions**.

As most of us will feel _x, _y, _width and _height to be properties of current/self class, but in your case it is parameters to the method.

Comment: Leaks are certainly possible under the ARC, it's just a lot harder to make them :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Yes I agree :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Is my answer better then earlier? :)

Comment: You still say leaks aren't possible, and that all ivars are released. That's still wrong. It's very easy to leak objects and their ivars if you don't know what ARC is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: And you're *still* talking about how "all ivars are released/autoreleased" which isn't always true.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no memory leak in your convenience method under ARC: the compiler is smart enough to deal with releasing the `v_txt` when the last strong reference to it is gone, employing autorelease behind the scenes if it is necessary.